# Прыжок не больше двух раз на C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Сразу говорю, я новичок в Unity и C#, но мне нужно сделать так, чтобы персонаж прыгал не больше двух раз, к примеру.

### Вот мой код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour {
 Rigidbody2D rb;
 Animator anim;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();

 }

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){ // нажатие ПРОБЕЛА для прыжка
        JumpMove();
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))  // нажатие W для прыжка
    {
        JumpMove() ;
    }
    if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") == 0){
        anim.SetInteger("Anim1", 0);
    } else{
        Flip();
    anim.SetInteger("Anim1", 1);
    }
    if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") >0 )
    {
        anim.SetInteger("Anim1", 2);
    }
    if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") <0)
    {
        anim.SetInteger("Anim1", 2);
    }

}
void ReloadLevel(){

}
void Flip(){
    if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0) transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
    if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0) transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0);

}
 void FixedUpdate(){
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * 5f, rb.velocity.y);

}
void JumpMove(){
    rb.AddForce(transform.up * 5f , ForceMode2D.Impulse);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делаем счётчик прыжков

```
   int countJump = 0;
```

В методе прыжка проверяем его значение, если меньше 2х прыгаем.

```
void JumpMove(){
  if(countJump < 2){
    rb.AddForce(transform.up * 5f , ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    countJump++; 
  } 
}
```

Для повторного использования прыжков просто обнули countJump

Comment: Еще,возможно,стоит добавить таймер для определения насколько часто может персонаж прыгать и по истечению таймера обнулять int countJump = 0; <- переменную

Comment: А как его можно реализовать, подскажите, пожалуйста?

Comment: @weraggsrhsethrt отметь как правильный и плюсек если не жалко

Comment: @weraggsrhsethrt попробуй сам помыслить над вопросом, погуглить. Иначе так и будешь на простое ждать ответ. Начинать стоит отсюда  https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials